# Font size too big for label in stack view

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, ios-autolayout

I want to use a font size of 54 pt for labels in a stack view (that's embedded in other stack views), but the labels do not adjust their size and the top of the text is cut off or not shown at all. This doesn't happen if I choose a smaller font size. Does anyone know how to fix this? I am mostly using autolayout and the constraints in the interface builder.

[image: Text cut off or missing in label]

Below is an image of the stack view configuration. A horizontal stack view with "00" and ":" is embedded in a vertical stack view with the label beneath it. And those four unities are embedded in another horizontal stack view.

I tried adding all the missing constraints but they made the whole app crash or the problem with the cut off number was still there so I have now removed them all (except constraints for the outer stack view.. it is only centered horizontally at the moment). I have now idea how I should go about creating the right constraints for the inner stack views...

[image]

Comment: can you tell a bit more about the constraints you set up, what the stack view hierarchy is and how the labels are configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set up a viewcontroller in storyboard to suit your needs. Compare it to your setup:

[image: horizontal stackview]
[image: vertical stackview]
[image: large label]
[image: small label]

Comment: thanks! I'll try your stack view configuration with a separate colon stack view and see if it helps!

Comment: how did you go about creating the empty label below the colon? It gets ignored as I run the app and the colon is too far down...

Comment: I set its text to `" "`.

Comment: I now have [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8unvbkucthtdqmh/Screen%20Shot%202017-08-17%20at%2022.27.12.png?dl=0)... whole label is showing but it's not really symmetrical and I can't seem to fix it with constraints... colons are still in the wrong place! do you have another tip?

p.s. I'll center the text later, I'm only concerned about the vertical position

Comment: the word "this" in my previous comment is a link to a screenshot of what it looks like now, it's just hard to see that it's a link!

Comment: The result... but not your setup 

Comment: here is my setup: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rdiiikpfbee21jj/Screen%20Shot%202017-08-17%20at%2023.34.06.png?dl=0

Comment: i only have constraints on the outermost stack view right now (it has a vertical and horizontal position) but I can't get the internal ones to look good

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152201/discussion-between-andre-slotta-and-eli6).